# Converting to the right format and counting items in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count

How do I convert df into df2, where df is given by:

```
> df
  ID  VALUES
1  1 a,b,c,d
2  2       a
3  3 c,d,f,g
```

and df2 should look something like:

```
> df2
  ID a b c d f g
1  1 1 1 1 1 0 0
2  2 1 0 0 0 0 0
3  3 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

where the values from df have been broken out into separate columns and 1s and 0s reflect whether or not the ID was associated with that value (from df).

Is there a specific function for this? I thought this is what table() did but if that's the case I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're suggesting it's a datafrrame but it's printing as though it is a matrix.

Comment: And this one from recently too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237877/r-split-data-to-frequency/35238311

Comment: thx for pointing me there.

Comment: I'm kind of annoyed that after walking back through the links of duplicate, the one question to which one can still add an answer is specifically focussed on data.table methods, which htis question is does not request and which my answer does not use.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that uses no extra packages:

```
 0 + t( sapply(df[['VALUES']], function(x) {
                               letters[1:6] %in% scan(text=x, what="", sep=",") }))
Read 4 items
Read 1 item
Read 4 items
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
a,b,c,d    1    1    1    1    0    0
a          1    0    0    0    0    0
c,d,f,g    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

It does return a matrix and it does depend on the VALUES column being character rather than factor. If you want to suppress the information messages from `scan` there is a parmeter for that. You could `cbind` this with the ID column:

```
 cbind( df["ID"], 0+ t( sapply(df[['VALUES']], function(x) {letters[1:6] %in% scan(text=x, what="", sep="," , quiet=TRUE) })) )

        ID 1 2 3 4 5 6
a,b,c,d  1 1 1 1 1 0 0
a        2 1 0 0 0 0 0
c,d,f,g  3 0 0 1 1 0 1
```